# Keystrokes have miraculously switched to French using Beamer

Tags: beamer, lyx, babel

Hi I'm using `Beamer` to prepare a presentation and for some weird reason the `keystroke` has decided to switch to French (it worked fine in the coursebook that I have already prepared).

As far as I can see the language is set everywhere to English UK (I'm using LyX). I've exported the LyX file to plain LaTeX and I can find the following

```
\usepackage{babel}
\makeatletter
\addto\extrasfrench{%
   \providecommand{\og}{\leavevmode\flqq~}%
   \providecommand{\fg}{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi~\frqq}%
}
```

I have no idea where the `\extrasfrench` comes from. Has this been introduced by Babel?

My colleagues tell me to keep the French keystrokes just for the entertainment value, but I would really rather like to switch them back to English!

Comment: I think it happened when copy/pasting bits of code from one LyX document to another. If I highlight everything with `Crtl+A` right click, choose Language and English this seems to resolve the problem.

Comment: Is this possibly a bug in LyX? I think it only happened on my Linux version, but worked fine in Windows.

Comment: If you can reproduce this, and you think this is a bug, notify the LyX developers by adding a ticket in the [bug tracker](http://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome). If you're unsure, perhaps ask on the [mailing list](http://www.lyx.org/MailingLists) first.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it looks like a bug in Lyx.